# Shell script based on a condition from a text file, and write robot framework test cases

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am working on Robot framework test cases. My requirement is to read below file and  compare values based on position. For example:

1. Line starting with 3. 3 is the ID number, I have to select that entire line, and compare values based on position.BRONYX starts at 9th position, should be compared to output at 44th position NEW YORK. BRONYX should change to NEWYORK in this example. How to extract strings based on position.

3^G^G^G^GBRONX^GNY^G10457^GUSA^G^G^GBRONX SHOULD CHANGE TO NEW YORK - DERIVED CITY EXAMPLE^G^G^G^GNEW YORK^GNY^G10457^G10457^G^GBRONX COUNTY^G^GBRONX^GNEW YORK^GUSA^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G40.845600^G-73.898500^G325^GSPU^GZ1^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^GNEW YORK-NEWARK-JERSEY CITY, NY-NJ-PA METROPOLITAN STATISTICAL AREA^G35620^GE020^GZC5X^GMMMMMVVV^G36005039500

example2: select the line with ID 2, In this example, MANHATTAN at 9th position should change to New York (position at 40).
2^G^G^G^GMANHATTAN^GNY^G^GUSA^G^G^GMANHATTAN SHOULD CHANGE TO NEW YORK - DERIVED CITY EXAMPLE^G^G^G^GNEW YORK^GNY^G^G^G^GNEW YORK^G^G^G^GUSA^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G40.783434^G-73.966249^G425^GSPU^GG3^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^GMMMMMVVM^G

Can you please help?

Comment: This is an obvious homework question.

Comment: It's "Bronx", not "bronyx". Your lines seem to consist of columns, fields, separated by "bell" characters, or character 7, shown as "^G" or control-g. If you set the separqtor to that character, awk would have little trouble with your task.

Comment: You need to share what you've tried so far, and what problems you encountered.  You may have confused this stack with a free coding service?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that each `^G` is a Control-G character, i.e., that the file is delimited using ASCII bell characters (`\a`), and that you want to set the 5th field to the value of the 15th field for each line:

```bsh
awk -F '\a' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { $5 = $15 }; 1' file >newfile
```

This sets the field separator to the ASCII bell character using `-F '\a'`.  It then sets the output field separator to the same character and continues by simply updating the 5th field to the value of the 15th field.  The trailing `1` in the code causes the modified record to be outputted.  The result is written to a file called `newfile` in this example.

Would you only that this affects lines that start with `2` or `3` in the first field, then use

```bsh
awk -F '\a' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 == 2 || $1 == 3 { $5 = $15 }; 1' file >newfile
```

Result formatted as a markdown table, just for presentation.  The 4th column is the `e` column, and the 15th column is the `o` column.

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z | aa | bb | cc | dd | ee | ff | gg | hh | ii | jj | kk | ll | mm | nn | oo | pp | qq | rr | ss | tt | uu | vv | ww |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 |  |  |  | NEW YORK | NY | 10,457 | USA |  |  | BRONX SHOULD CHANGE TO NEW YORK - DERIVED CITY EXAMPLE |  |  |  | NEW YORK | NY | 10,457 | 10,457 |  | BRONX COUNTY |  | BRONX | NEW YORK | USA |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40.846… | -73.898… | 325 | SPU | Z1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | NEW YORK-NEWARK-JERSEY CITY, NY-NJ-PA METROPOLITAN STATISTICAL AREA | 35,620 | E020 | ZC5X | MMMMMVVV | 36,005,039,500 |
| 2 |  |  |  | NEW YORK | NY |  | USA |  |  | MANHATTAN SHOULD CHANGE TO NEW YORK - DERIVED CITY EXAMPLE |  |  |  | NEW YORK | NY |  |  |  | NEW YORK |  |  |  | USA |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40.783… | -73.966… | 425 | SPU | G3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | MMMMMVVM |  |

Answer (score 0):

Welcome at SE. A few ideas:

- Pipe the file through `hexdump` or `xxd` to look at readable representations.
- Use `strings` to extract readable text from the file.
  I think this one may help you.
- Use `cut` and/or `head` plus `tail` to extract parts of lines or select lines respectively. `sed` or `awk` can be your friends too, but only if you learn to use them. That will take years.

> How to extract strings based on position

Hard to say based on this question.

> should be compared to output

Are you asking us to write your solutions? What have you tried. Did you read `man awk` as suggested? Or doesn't Linux come with documentation in Hindi?

### Example

**If** the string is fixed length, and **if** the file has no newlines, then maybe you can use a single `cut` invocation:

```
$ echo my long string | cut -c4-8
```

output:

```
long
```

NB. please use the editor or Markdown formatting for better display of your data.

Answer (score 0):

First I found and replaced all the Ctrl+G characters to `|` (pipe) using

```
sed 's/^G/|/g' test.csv > output.csv
```

I was able to print the entire line using

```
grep ^6 output.csv
```

With `6` being the ID number.

```
6|LAKELINE MALL|||AUSTIN|TX||USA|||MALL EXAMPLE - POI|11066 PECAN PARK BLVD|||AUSTIN|TX|78613|78613||TRAVIS||AUSTIN|CEDAR PARK|USA||||||||30.468408|-97.803570|140|SPU|NA||||||||||||UUUUUVVM|
```